# Загрузка 2х изображений и вывод 1го на экран с помощью Flask Restful API

Tags: python, изображения, flask

Нужно загружать на сервер **две фотографии**, после чего они объединяются и получившееся должна выводится на экран (Код для обедининия не нужен). *Если одну фотографию я знаю как отправить на сервер ([Нашел в документации](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)), то две не знаю.* Как переписать код под загрузку 2х фотографий. Желательно разеснить как это работает, так как я еще не совсем разобрался в *Flask Restful API*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще бы чуть чуть погуглили:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    filenames = []
    for file in uploaded_files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            filenames.append(filename)
    return render_template('upload.html', filenames=filenames)
```

Comment: Да, это вечная беда)